# How to Update ListBox using CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My application changes the contents of a ListBox based on a user selection elsewhere. Ultimately, this list will be filtered as well. I would like to use CollectionViewSource to help manage the items in the ListBox. I add items to an ObservableCollection, but don't see any items in the ListBox.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DataFileView" Source="DataFilesCollection"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

...

<ListBox x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataFileView}}" 
         Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="DataFile_Select">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:ExploreDataItem}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The `DataFilesCollection` is an `ObservableCollection<ExploreDataItem>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `Binding` to the source of the `CollectionViewSource`. I don't find any other mistake in your code. Everything seems to be right. Hope your `DataFilesCollection` is not empty either.

See below corrected code :

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="DataFileView" Source="{Binding DataFilesCollection}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still no dice. The collection has 100 elements in it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you can show entire code, which is testable, then can check.

Comment: The problem was that I was not setting DataContext properly. Thanks for your help.